# Achieve airtight seal of exterior door

Tags: doors, windows, sound-proofing, seal

Our balcony door does not seal well, which results in frequent visits from spiders and an increased noise from the outside.
I first thought the issue is a gap at the top and bottom (both gaps on the same side, not the side with the hinges) but shimming videos do not cover this case.
Also, testing with a small paper strip, it seems that the issue is all around the door (can pull paper strip free with shut door).

I tried weather strips but then I cannot shut the door anymore. The gaps seem to have
different thickness on the hinge and knob side.

What's the best way to fix this and are there any videos you can recommend?
House is only 8 years old, which surprises me..
Thanks!
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Pictures of the door and of the gaps will help.  Different types of weatherstripping for different gaps and doors.

Comment: Is it a metal door? If it is, magnetic weather stripping can work magic.

Comment: I added pictures. Thanks!

Comment: Note that many houses leak like a sieve anyway. You may get more benefit out of a proper air-sealing pass. In the US, some utility companies will now pay for their customers to do an energy audit, and the recommended work may be subsidized and/or eligible for tax credits; that's where I would suggest starting unless the draft from this one door is really obnoxious. (Not quite an answer, I think.)

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as an airtight door on a house. It's not a reasonable goal. You'll get *close*, but never perfect. They're not designed for a submarine.

There's presumably weather stripping in place already, so you either have a misadjustment or the building has settled. (This is *more* common in a newer building, not less, as you've implied.) You should not be adding more weather stripping to what the factory provided.

You haven't said what hardware we're looking at, so I can't offer specific advice. Look for adjustable hinges and threshold. Check whether the gaps between the door and the jamb are parallel and not larger than about 3/16" (~5mm). Look for damage. Adjust what needs adjusting and replace what needs replacing. Ask a more specific question if you like.

---

In the new photos I see that your hinges are not adjustable (and have been mangled by someone using the wrong size screwdriver). So, I suggest you look at the door latch. It may just need to be adjusted so the door pulls closed more tightly.

One easy fix is often to remove the strike plate and bend the 90° tab out slightly, so that the door bolt is forced further along the door swing path. Otherwise you may need to move the screws. I can't tell from here.

Comment: Thanks for your message. I added a picture of the three hinges the door has (top middle bottom). Not sure how much the bolt make it more difficult to adjust the door.

Comment: The door let's through a lot of noise. You can hear people talk which was not the case in our old flat. Also not sure to what extent it is normal for medium spiders to enter through the gaps. The glass is thick double glass and you can clearly hear the noise comes in from the gaps

Comment: I am not sure if the door latch will help. If I pull on the door to "shut it more", this does not help with the gaps. So you are saying that playing with the screws will not do anything? I have to check if the other screws have also been mangled by the previous owner..

Comment: "I can hear people talk, but I couldn't at the old flat", are you sure @Groenendijk that the sound is coming through the door, not the wall? It may be that the walls at your old place were better insulated than at the new place and that sound is coming through there.

Comment: You can pinpoint just with your ears it's coming from the upper and lower corner where there are gaps @freeman